# openOrCreateDatabase in different class causes null pointer exception

Tags: android, class

I have defined a new class to use in my project and I get null pointer exception in the context

Here is what i coded :

```
public class OurClass extends Activity {
     private dha mContext;
     private dhaService sContext; 


     public OurClass(dha dha) {
          sContext=null;
           mContext = dha;
        }

     public OurClass(dhaService dhx) {
            sContext = dhx;
            mContext=null;
        }
    public  void put_default_value( String varname, String value) {
        Log.i("dha",     "d1");
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        Log.i("dha",     "d1.5");
        if (mContext==null) {
            Log.i("dha",     "dx1");
         db = sContext.openOrCreateDatabase("gipi.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
         Log.i("dha",    "dx2");
        } else {
            Log.i("dha",     "dz1");
        db = android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("gipi.db", null);
        Log.i("dha",     "dz2");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually checking that the `Context`s are valid before using them.

For example, if `OurClass(dhaService dhx)` is called with a `null` `Context`, then `putDefaultValue` will fail with a `NullPointerException` because `sContext` is assigned the value of `dhx` without checking either `dhx` or `sContext` for valid values.

On a side note, neither `sContext`, nor `mContext` are being initialised, which means that with the lack of proper checking you have right now, you could easily inadvertently call `put_default_value`, while never actually having called either of the constructors. This is not best practice.

---

EDIT:

One way to help guard against this is to make the default constructor private, so that an instance of the class **must** be created by calling one of the constructors you have provided:

```
private:
    OurClass ( void ) {
    }
```

Even if you do that, you still need to properly validate your inputs to at least detect null pointers - you can't just assume it will all work as you intend, since it clearly isn't right now.